# Delphi: a modal form flickers

Tags: delphi, show, flicker, appearance, tform

There is a modal form with: labels, buttons, group boxes.

I call from a Form 1 on a button click: `Form2.ShowModal;`

When the form 2 appears first - all is ok because of a blend effect. But next form's appearance has a flicker, especially labels, buttons. I tried to use `DoubleBuffered:=True/False and ParentFont:=True/False (in case of a group box, frame)`. It doesn't help :(

Can anybody help please? Thanks!

Comment: Can you tell us what provokes the flicker? Does it flicker even with do user interaction?

Comment: Do you destroy the form and recreate it or just hide and show?

Comment: @David Heffernan and Sam, it flickers when a from appears. I don't destroy and recreate it, I hide and show it. I have 10 labels, 10 buttons, 5 edits, a group box on a form->all flickers.

Comment: if to make a right anchor for all control and resize a form -> they flicker but not much -> Form's DoubleBuffered:=Enabled -> no flickers on resizing but the flicker still exists on form's appearance.

Answer (score 2):

OK this will do the trick, replace this solution if there are any better...

**1st**, `OnFormCreate`

```
Form2.AlphaBlendValue := 0;
Form2.AlphaBlend := true;
```

**2nd**, Add Timer, `OnTimerEvent`

```
Form2.AlphaBlendValue := 255;  
Form2.AlphaBlend := false;
Timer1.Enable := False;
```

**3rd** `OnFormShow`

```
Timer1.Enable := True;
```

Comment: I can't believe I happened across this.  I was having a very similar issue with a TCppWebBrowser control.  When I called ShowModal on the form holding the browser control, the control would flicker on appearance.  This fixed it!